# How to determine what artifacts are built from a maven reactor plan (ie: including sub modules)?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

(Note: this question was originally posed by Dan Allen on Google+ here: https://plus.google.com/114112334290393746697/posts/G6BLNgjyqeQ)

If I ran 'mvn install', what artifacts would it install? Or, if I ran 'mvn deploy', what artifacts would it deploy?

This would likely be a fairly straightforward plugin to write, but I don't want to re-invent this if it's already available somewhere programmatically.  It seems like this should be readily available somewhere.

Comment: I don't think this is so straightforward. For example, if you use assembly plugin, you can specify if its products should be attached to module artifact (`<attach>` parameter). So this plugin (if it existed) should be able to take such cases into account.

Answer (score 4):

As [Andrew Logvinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966590/andrew-logvinov) already commented, any maven plugin could attach
additional artifacts. So I don't think this would be possible without actually
building the project and executing all plugins bound to lifecycle phases upto `package`.

I don't know of any preexisting plugins doing this, the closes would probably
be to run an actual deploy into a temporary directory and then list the
contained files. To avoid modifying your local repository while doing this, you
would want to avoid the `install` phase. The `verify` phase happens directly
before `install`, the deploy mojo can then be invoked explicitly.

The [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) allows to specify an alternative repository using a file url like this:

```
mvn verify deploy:deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshots::default::file:///home/jh/Temp/repository
```

The simplest implementation of a maven plugin listing all attached artifacts could look like this:

```java
/**
 * @goal list-artifacts
 * @phase verify
 */
public class ListArtifactsMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        Collection<Artifact> artifacts = new ArrayList<Artifact>();
        artifacts.add(project.getArtifact());
        artifacts.addAll(project.getAttachedArtifacts());

        for (Artifact artifact : artifacts) {
            System.out.println("Artifact: " + artifact);
        }
    }
}
```